# Where can I find the source code Apache uses to process .htaccess?

Tags: c, apache

I'd like to look at the source code Apache uses to process .htaccess files. I've downloaded and grepped the Apache source files with no luck.

Comment: You can find it somewhere in the Apache source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm suspicious of your ability to grep..  I just downloaded the httpd source and it mentions `htaccess` everywhere.  Why not start by looking at the function `ap_parse_htaccess` defined in `server/config.c`.

Comment: Thanks! My grepping is OK, I downloaded the modules instead of the httpd source (duh).